# xbar plots in pgfplots 1.12 gives empty y axis range warning

Tags: pgfplots

The following MWE works great with [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) v1.11, but gives a warning about an empty y axis range with v1.12. I didn't see anything in the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/README) that would indicate a change has been made to the `xbar` style. How can I fix this and restore the 1.11 behavior (without setting `compat=1.11`)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xbar,
    xmin=-60, xmax=80,
    axis y line*=middle,
]
\addplot[blue,fill,draw=none] table[x={750-K}, y expr=\coordindex] {
 750-K
 62.099
 62.046
 56.304
-44.258
-28.826
 18.740
-14.653
 14.402
-12.907
 12.295
 };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Output from `compat=1.11`:
[image: v1.11]

Output from `compat=1.12`:
[image: v1.12]

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this. I get your result for `compat=1.11` regardless of whether I use `compat=1.11` or `compat=1.12`.

Comment: @erik Thanks for checking! I'll check on another computer in the morning :)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run it with `lualatex`? The main change in `1.12` is that `pgfplots` makes intensive use of `lua`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger `lualatex` doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a fixed bug in pgfplots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears if and only if you use `lualatex`. Apparently, the new `lua backend` fails with this plot type.

Possible (alternative) Workarounds are

1. use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or
2. use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, lua backend=false}` or
3. add `lua backend=false` to the offending plot or
4. use `pdflatex` to compile your document.

I will take care of the bug.

Comment: bug is fixed in the developer version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by erik in a comment, this problem may not be reproducible. In fact, I cannot reproduce it myself by copying the code out of the question. Nonetheless, my original file still has this problem. I am able to resolve the issue by adding `point meta=explicit symbolic` into the `axis` options:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xbar,
    xmin=-60, xmax=80,
    axis y line*=middle,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
]
\addplot[blue,fill,draw=none] table[x index={0}, y expr=\coordindex] {%
 750-K
 75
 62.046
 56.304
-44.258
-28.826
 18.740
-14.653
 14.402
-12.907
 12.295
 };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```